# (JS, Promise) How to wait for promises from multiple map functions

Tags: javascript, promise

I have three arrays:

```
const firstArray = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const secondArray = ['i', 'j', 'k']
const thirdArray = ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

I have to send multiple requests using all possible combinations and wait for all the responses to be resolved before continuing.
So I tried to do it like this

```
const getPromises = () => {
    const promises = firstArray.map(first => {
          return secondArray.map(second => {
            return thirdArray.map(third => {
              return axios.get(`https://someurl.com/${first}/${second}/${third}`)
                                .then(response => response);
            })
          })
        })
      return Promise.all(promises)
    }
```

And I have another method where I tried to get returned values from this method

```
const getvalues = async () => {
    const someVariable = await getPromises();
}
```

But it didn't work out. Variable `someVariable` just had unresolved promises.

What I did wrong?

Comment: `Promise.all()` expects an array of `Promise`s but `promises` is an array of arrays of arrays (reduced example of your transformed input: `[[["a/i/x","a/i/y"],["a/j/x","a/j/y"]],[["b/i/x","b/i/y"],["b/j/x","b/j/y"]]]`)

Comment: Try using `.flat(2)` on your promises array

Comment: Do you really have to bombard the server with `firstArray.length * secondArray.length * thirdArray.length` single requests? Why don't you just send the complete "raw" input and let the server do all the work.

Comment: I agree with @Andreas Letting the server do this job would gain speed for your process.

Comment: @Andreas, could you please tell me how to do it, how to send complete "raw" input? Unfortunately I have no idea how it exactly works and what are the benefits of this approach. Any link would also be helpful as I don't even know how to look for it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

---

```
const getPromises = () => Promise.all(function* () {
    for (let first of firstArray)
        for (let second of secondArray)
            for (let third of thirdArray)
                yield axios.get(`https://someurl.com/${first}/${second}/${third}`)
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Approaching to solve your problem with `.map` doesn't work, because nested map-functions are returning nested arrays and `Promise.all` expects an array of promises as entries not arrays itself.

The best approach might be using nested `for...of` loops:

```js
const firstArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const secondArray = ['i', 'j', 'k'];
const thirdArray = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

const getPromises = () => {
  const promises = [];
  for (let first  of firstArray )
  for (let second of secondArray)
  for (let third  of thirdArray ) {
    promises.push(axios.get(`https://someurl.com/${first}/${second}/${third}`));
  }
  return Promise.all(promises);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that shows what you need:

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const b = ['i', 'j', 'k'];
const c = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

let promises = [];

a.forEach((i1) => {
  b.forEach((i2) => {
    c.forEach((i3) => {
      let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
          res([i1, i2, i3])
        }, 250)
      }).then(([j1, j2, j3]) => console.log(j1, j2, j3));
      promises.push(promise);
    })
  })
});

Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log("finish"));
```

Just replace the `setTimeout` with your `axios.get(https://someurl.com/${first}/${second}/${third})`